# Bootstrap dropdown submit on select

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to send data based on the dropdown menu. So if I click on Delete I will post deleteall

```
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary btn-white dropdown-toggle">
    Action
    <span class="ace-icon fa fa-caret-down icon-on-right"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-white" name="dropdown">
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="inactiveall" value="yes" onclick="document.forms['search'].submit(); return false;">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="activeall"  value="yes" onclick="document.forms['search'].submit(); return false;">Inactive</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" name="deleteall" value="yes" onclick="document.forms['search'].submit(); return false;">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `if I click on Delete I will post deleteall`

Comment: Your question is not clear.Please be specific. @user1282355

Comment: $_POST[deleteall] = "yes";

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have a link to the top of the page and some JavaScript. Replace that with a submit button.

```
<button name="deleteall" value="yes"> Delete </button>
```